# iTerm settings gone after restart

Tags: iterm

I restarted my Mac and something weird has happened. I had custom iTerm settings (the way I the prompt display's - I removed the machine etc, etc). I wouldn't mind just loosing that when I restarted but I seem to be on ruby 1.8.7 and have lost rvm.

I have restarted my machine loads of times why have my settings disappeared this time? How can I get them back?

Comment: It turned out my .bash_profile file had deleted itself. Time Machine backup restore of this file later returned iTerm to how I left it.